# TextureCube to Texture2DArray: from sampling vector to uv + slice index

Tags: 3d, directx, shader, hlsl

**Premise**

I'm currently developing a graphical application and, due to unforeseen limitations with the framework I'm using, I need to convert my TextureCube textures into a Texture2DArray with 6 slices.

While going from one format to the other is not really an issue, sampling from the Texture2DArray using a 3D vector constitutes a harder challenge.

**Question**

Given:

- A 3D vector previously used to sample a TextureCube
- A Texture2DArray representation of the same TextureCube

What is the most efficient way to write a (HLSL) shader function that returns a float3 coord, in which:

- coord.z is the index of the correct slice within the Texture2DArray
- coord.xy are the uv coordinates used to sample the selected slice

**Current Progress**

At the moment this is my current progress:

- I know from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980530/selecting-the-face-of-a-cubemap-in-glsl), that the vector component with the biggest magnitude dictates the correct face to be selected.
- Once a face is selected using the component with the biggest magnitude, I think that the remaining components can be used as uv coordinates (assuming the vector is normalized).
- I'm not sure how to treat cases in which two of the vector components, or all three of the vector components have the same magnitude (for instance (0.5,0.5,0.5)). I assume that, if the texture is somewhat continuous from pixel to pixel, picking one face, rather then the next should not yield particular differences.

**Final Note**

Please assume that the Cubemap faces are sorted within the using the [default DX11 ordering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476906(v=vs.85).aspx), i.e. +X, -X, +Y, -Y, +Z, -Z. I also want to stress that efficiency is extremely important.

Comment: "*due to unforeseen limitations with the framework I'm using, I need to convert my TextureCube textures into a Texture2DArray with 6 slices.*" I cannot imagine what those limitations might be. In D3D11, it is perfectly possible to take a 2D array texture with 6+ layers and create a cubemap view of it. Why are you unable to do that?

Comment: @NicolBolas I've actually first built a prototype of my project in C++/D3D11, but now I'm porting it to Unity. While on the D3D11 side everything works fine, Unity offers a very poor support of TextureCube, thus yielding my question above. I can further explain what I mean with "poor support" if you're curious...

Comment: Keep in mind that a Texture2DArray only works on ``D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0`` or better hardware.

Comment: @ChuckWalboum Yep, good reminder.